# SwiftUI Binding to Computed Property?

Tags: ios, swift, data-binding, swiftui

I have two classes, one is the ContentView who is displaying the information from my data source. The data source is my CharacterRepository.

What I'm struggling with right now is making sure I always have a sorted list inside of my CharacterRepository.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
class CharacterRepository: ObservableObject {
    @Published public var characters = [Character(name: "Nott the Brave",
                                                  initiative: 23,
                                                  isActive: false),
                                        Character(name: "Caduceus Clay",
                                                  initiative: 2,
                                                  isActive: false),
                                        ...]
    ...
}
```

and

```
struct InitiativeTrackerScreen: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var characterRepository: CharacterRepository

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(characterRepository.characters) { entry in
                        CharacterListElement(character: entry)
                    }
    ...
```

Now my intended approach would be something like turning the characters variable into a computed property that runs the "sorted by" function every time the get gets executed. Unfortunately, Binding to a computed property is not yet possible in SwiftUI (not sure, will it ever be?).

Can someone please help me with this? I don't want to go back to the old approach of sorting and redrawing every time something changes. That's not why I am using SwiftUI with ist sweet bindings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it may be unnecessary overhead to be sorting the data in the property getter.

The simple (*and performance-conscious*) solution is to sort the data when it changes, and then to update a `@Published` non-computed property and bind to that:

```
class CharacterRepository: ObservableObject {
    func updateCharacters(_ characters: [Character]) {
       self.characters = characters.sorted() // or whatever sorting strategy you need...
    }

    @Published public var characters = [Character(name: "Nott the Brave",
                                                  initiative: 23,
                                                  isActive: false),
                                        Character(name: "Caduceus Clay",
                                                  initiative: 2,
                                                  isActive: false),
                                        ...]
    ...
}
```

If you prefer to be über-purist about this at the cost of performance, then you can manually create a [`Binding`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding) - something like this:

```
class CharacterRepository: ObservableObject {
   let sortedCharacters: Binding<[Character]>
   ...


   init() { 
      self.sortedCharacters = .init(get: { return characters.sorted() }, set: { self.characters = $0 })
   }

   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That's actually what I thought, but that means I will have a state for the view inside of my Data Source wich is not a good separation of concerns. But honestly, I think this is probably my best bet for now. It means though that I will always need to make sure the array is sorted if something is done to it.

The second one is currently giving me ergots because I'm using self before all members are initialised. But that's fixable. :)

I'll give both methods a shot! Thanks so much!

Comment: @bob_mosh You're welcome.
I would strongly recommend the first approach - sorting on update is always going to be a lot faster than sorting every time the data is requested by the view.

Comment: Yeah that's true. That way I can decide when to run the code instead of running it every time the data is used. Not a huge concern for me right now, but might be in the future.

Comment: I went with the first option for now. Had to add a couple of calls here and there but works like a charm. :) It's not reactive however.

Answer (score 1):

I like to answer by related question. For what do you ever need some binding to computed property?

```
class CharacterRepository: ObservableObject {
    @Published public var characters = [Character(name: "Nott the Brave",
                                                  initiative: 23,
                                                  isActive: false),
                                        Character(name: "Caduceus Clay",
                                                  initiative: 2,
                                                  isActive: false),
                                        ...]
    ...
    var sorted: [Character] {
        characters.sorted()
    }
}
```

is all you need.

Comment: Fo example to capture the data that is entered and do validation checks before adding it to an array or for example to deliver a sorted list back, based on a different variable that handles the sorting. A computed property would be a perfect fit for that.

Comment: computed property is getter only. so binding to it is impossible by definition. you could return some cashed value, or whatever you want from it, let say "precomputed"  sorted values which were sorted in some background  task ... there is not necessary to wrap it to any @Published property wrapper, just because if the stored array changes (you add or modify some values), SwiftUI is informed about.

Comment: if you would like to return different results, you have to wrap (and modify from UI) parameters of sorting procedure, not the result self.

Comment: Yeah that's what I am doing right now. I felt like having a data source that is automatically sorted based on my state for the sorting could be a smart way to handle things, but it seems like keeping the two things separate is not really the smartest way to got. :) Thanks for the input! This was really helpful!