# SwiftUI - Editing a value of an item in a Codable Array Cannot use mutating member on immutable value

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, codable, mutating-function

I have a built up `List` with using an array of `Codable` type called `Package`. At some point, I need to update the `isFavorite` value of an `Package` item when user taps `favorite` button in the list. However I am getting the error of `Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'package' is a 'let' constant`. First I tried to directly change the value in the action. It did not work, so the point I got so far is below.

Obviously the code is longer than that but I just wanted make it simple and deleted irrelevant parts.

`SwiftUIView`

```
struct AView: View {

    @ObservedObject var store: JSONController

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(self.store.packages) { (package) in
                return self.row(package)
            }
        }
    }

    private func row(_ package: Package) -> some View {
        HStack{
            Text(package.name)
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                package.changeFavoriteState()
            }) {
                Image(systemName: package.isFavorite ? "star.fill" : "star")
            }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

`Package.struct`

```
struct Package: Codable, Identifiable {

    var id: UUID
    var isFavorite: Bool

    mutating func changeFavoriteState() {
        self.isFavorite.toggle()
    }
}
```

`PackageList.struct`

```
struct PackageList: Codable {

    var packages: [Package]

    private enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case packages
    }

    init(){
        self.packages = [Package]()
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        do {
            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            self.packages = try container.decode([Package].self, forKey: .packages)
        }catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription+" Initializing packages with an empty array.")
            self.packages = [Package]()
        }
    }
}
```

`JSONController.class`

```
class JSONController: ObservableObject {

    @Published var packages: [Package] = [Package]()

    init(){
        self.readJSONFile(from: "packageList")
    }

    func readJSONFile(from url: String) {
        //stuff
    }

}
```

And finally the error I got,

[image: error]

Comment: try passing package as a binding from the list. that way you should be able to update it's value

Comment: I tried to put `self.$store.packages` but did not work. `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'List<_, _>' with an argument list of type '(Binding<[Package]>, @escaping (inout Package) -> some View)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is simple, you need access the value, not its copy, provided by List

```
import SwiftUI

struct Package {
    var flag: Bool
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var arr = [Package(flag: true), Package(flag: false), Package(flag: true)]
    var body: some View {
        List(arr.indices, id:\.self) { (index) in
            Text(self.arr[index].flag.description).onTapGesture {
                self.arr[index].flag.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]

or using the ObservableObject

```
import SwiftUI

struct Package: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var flag: Bool
}
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var arr = [Package(flag: true), Package(flag: false), Package(flag: true)]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = Model()
    var body: some View {
        List(model.arr.indices) { (idx) in
            Text(self.model.arr[idx].flag.description)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.model.arr[idx].flag.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

which is generally the same ... but in more complex scenarios preferable

UPDATE based on request
You have to redefine row function

```
import SwiftUI

struct Package: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var flag: Bool
}
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var arr = [Package(flag: true), Package(flag: false), Package(flag: true)]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = Model()
    var body: some View {
        List(model.arr.indices) { (idx) in
            self.row(flag: self.$model.arr[idx].flag)
        }
    }

    func row(flag: Binding<Bool>)-> some View {
        Text(flag.wrappedValue.description)
            .onTapGesture {
                flag.wrappedValue.toggle()
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Or the second option

```
import SwiftUI

struct Package: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var flag: Bool
}
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var arr = [Package(flag: true), Package(flag: false), Package(flag: true)]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = Model()
    var body: some View {
        List(model.arr.indices) { (idx) in
            self.row(idx: idx)
        }
    }

    func row(idx: Int)-> some View {
        Text(model.arr[idx].flag.description)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.model.arr[idx].flag.toggle()
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

UPDATE with conditional sorting

```
import SwiftUI

struct Package: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    var flag: Bool
}
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var arr = [Package(id: 1, flag: true), Package(id: 3, flag: false), Package(id: 2, flag: true)]
    @Published var ascending = false

    var sorted: [Package] {
        arr.sorted { (p0, p1) -> Bool in
            let sort = (p0.id < p1.id)
            return ascending ? !sort : sort
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = Model()

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Toggle(isOn: $model.ascending) {
                Text("ascending")
            }.padding(.horizontal)

            List(model.sorted.indices, id: \.self) { (idx) in
                self.row(idx: idx)
            }
        }
    }

    func row(idx: Int)-> some View {
        Text(verbatim: model.sorted[idx].flag.description + ": " + model.sorted[idx].id.description)
            .onTapGesture {
                if let i = self.model.arr.firstIndex (where: { (p) -> Bool in
                    self.model.sorted[idx].id == p.id
                }) {
                    self.model.arr[i].flag.toggle()
                }
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but it just fails at `row` function. same error as in the question.

Comment: Can you try tihs for a scenario where there is another `View` that gets a `Package` as a parameter. By `View` I mean like a a view that handles a single `row`

Comment: @Faruk you have to pass binding to value, not package itself, or index (another option). see update

Comment: Tell me your address so I can send some goods from my homeland. @user3441734

Comment: @Faruk :-) :-) :-)

Comment: One more question though, I have a sort function inside my observableobject class. after this toggle, how can I trigger that sort?

Comment: @Faruk use computed property in your model, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60314241/swiftui-binding-to-computed-property/60316884#60316884

Comment: So I already have similar implemation. When the specific sorting option changes I am calling a func that sorts the packages in place. From your answer I could not get how can I trigger that complex sorting function when a value of package in the list changes. The thing is I need that list to be sorted all the time by some set rules and I already have a function that does that when a sorting options changes.

Comment: @Faruk see last update. in real application all business logic has to be part of model, use SwiftUI for presentation only.

Comment: I thought I have deleted the my last comment. I was calling the sort function in the wrong place. As you said, I have my sort function inside of the model not the view. I just called it right after changing the boolean value we solved before. Anyway, let it this way maybe some other people may take advantage of this. Really appreciated for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Change the signature of your function to

```
private func row(_ package: inout Package) -> some View
```

Why is that necessary? Because when you are passing a parameter to a function, that parameter is a `let` constant. `Package` is a `struct` so modifying any of its properties means actually modifying the instance itself. Which you cannot do, because it's a `let` constant.

Another thing is that since `Package` is a `struct` it means that when you are passing it to your function, you are actually passing a **copy**, not the original value.

An `inout` parameter has a value that is passed in to the function, is modified by the function, and is passed back out of the function to replace the original value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However after I added `inout` parameter it said `Passing value of type 'Package' to an inout parameter requires explicit '&'` where I call the `row` function. And I put `&` before `package` that I am sending in. After that it throws the same error `Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: 'package' is a 'let' constant` where I call the `row` function.

Comment: @Faruk thats because in List(self.store.packages) { (package) in
                return self.row(package)
            } the package is again the copy

Comment: I guessed that but could not find any solution when it comes to List

Comment: @Faruk see my answer